Is there anything different about the Intel icelake architecture?
I'm using Bochs to running a toy operating system kernel written by myself.
When running on CPUs based on other microarchitectures it is working, but when I select 'icelake-u' architecture, it is not working. It prompts "Legacy Paging: asked to set dirty on paging leaf entry with R/W bit clear". What caused this?

Processors that have Control Flow Enforcement Technology support (including Icelake and Tigerlake I believe) enforce new rules. I assume your BOCHS was built with CET support and for processors that support CET it is doing an additional check.  The comments in BOCHS say A processor that supports CET will never set the dirty flag in a paging-structure entry in which the R/W flag is clear . See https://github.com/bochs-emu/Bochs/blob/971576e32f15acad507b1089fd959b39488da6c9/bochs/cpu/paging.cc#L1244

In section 4.8 (Access and Dirty Flags) of the Intel Software Development Manual Volume 3 there is a note that says the same thing Specifically, a processor that supports CET will never set the dirty flag in a
paging-structure entry in which the R/W flag is clear.
